# Find the domain convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Consider the series $$\sum_{n\geq 1}^{}\dfrac{x^n(1-x^n)}{n}.$$Find
> the domain of (point-wise) convergence of the series.

My attempt:
$\sum_{n\geq 1}^{}\dfrac{x^n}{n}$ converges on $[-1,1)$.
$\sum_{n\geq 1}^{}\dfrac{x^{2n}}{n}$ converges on $(-1,1)$.
It's easy to see that the given sum diverges at $x=-1$,converges at $x=1$.
So, the given sum converges on $(-1,1]$. I don't know how to deal with the case when $x>1$,$x<-1$ (since the sum of $2$ divergent series does not mean the sum itself diverges)

Comment: Beware, you can only safely separate the two series if they're absolutely convergent. Here you don't need to do that at all, just use the ratio test.

Comment: How I can apply the ratio test? I see nothing here

Comment: Do you know how to apply the ratio test on functional series?

Comment: Yes, but it comes to nothing

Comment: @Bcpicao is this a power series?

Comment: @SineoftheTime no,it isnt. That why I dont understand Bcpicao idea

Comment: @SineoftheTime I agree it is not. What I meant is that you can apply the ratio test nevertheless if you discuss w.r.t. $x$. I guess a functional series is a more adequate term.

Comment: @Bcpicao maybe you meant something like this: you fix $x_0$ and then study the numerical series applying the ratio test?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider rough inequalities to compare to other simpler series.

Let call $a_n=\dfrac{x^n(1-x^n)}{n}$ and $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$

- $x=1\implies a_n=0$ therefore $S$ is trivially convergent.
- $x=-1\implies a_{2n}=0$ and $a_{2n+1}=-\frac 2{2n+1}$ therefore $S$ is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series.
- $|x|>1\implies |a_n|\sim \frac{x^{2n}}n\not\to 0$ therefore $S$ is trivially divergent.

You can also say $|a_n|=\dfrac{x^{2n}}n\underbrace{|1-\frac 1{x^n}|}_{>\frac 12\text{ for n large}}>\dfrac{x^{2n}}{2n}\not\to 0$

- finally $|x|<1\implies 0\le(1-x^n)\le 2$

$0\le \sum |a_n|\le \sum\frac{2|x|^n}n\le 2\sum |x|^n$ which is a geometric convergent series.

Therefore $S$ is absolutely convergent ($\sum |a_n|$ increasing and bounded thus convergent).

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, applying the ratio test, we get:

$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{n}{n+1}\frac{x^{n+1}(1-x^{n+1})}{x^{n}(1-x^{n})}= \frac{n}{n+1}x \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x^{n}}$

From this, one can see that the series converges absolutely for $x<1$ and diverges for $x>1$. The cases for $x=\pm 1$ can be treated separately, as you pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be divergence. Because $ \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{x^n(1-x^n)}{n} \neq 0$ when$|x|>1$

Let's $ a_m(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{x^n(1-x^n)}{n} $ .Suppose {$a_m(x)$}  is convergence when $|x|>1$. there exist a real number $a(x)=\lim_{m \to \infty}a_m(x)$ . But

$0\neq \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{x^n(1-x^n)}{n}= \lim_{n \to +\infty}(a_{n+1}(x)-a_n(x))= \lim_{n \to +\infty}a_{n+1}(x)-\lim_{n \to +\infty}a_n(x)=a(x)-a(x)=0$

is a contradiction. So when $|x|>1$,this serise is divergence.